# How to start with a brand new battery?

Tags: battery

Is there a special procedure to be followed when installing a brand new battery ?

Like

- discharging it completely, or not;
- leave it fully charged for a certain amount of time,
- etc...

*(It's a battery of a MacBook Pro)*

Comment: I would caution that all unibody MacBook self-calibrate. I have written a nice summary of this for a similar question about macBook batteries in late 2012. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73310/is-it-advisable-to-calibrate-the-battery-on-a-macbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no special procedure for a new MB/MBP battery. I recently replaced my MBP's battery myself, and searched Apple support documents for care instructions, but I couldn't find anything other than the standard "drain it once in a while."

Btw, my new battery was completely discharged, and it took about 12 hours to fully charge it. I left it on charge overnight and started using the MBP as usual the next day.

Comment: Please see new answer regarding this, including support documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Calibrating your battery means you will preserve the battery life for longer.

On its own website Apple says that you should calibrate your battery during the first week and then once every month, and then whenever you purchase new batteries.

Source: [Apple Support](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/9036.html)

Answer (score 1):

Even better: http://www.apple.com/batteries/
It has a lot of good information which can be applied across the board. Although portables with built-in batteries are pre-calibrated and do not require the calibration procedure outlined in [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1490)

1- charge battery until it is full charged and let sit for 2-4 hrs fully charged.

2- remove external power source and let unit run until you get the "battery running on reserve" message from the system (usually around the 2-5% mark).

3- Allow the system to put itself to sleep at this point, or you can put the computer to sleep yourself (waiting for the front LED to ebb) and then remove the battery from the system and leave battery out of the computer for 2-4 hrs at 0% charge.

3.1- I like to tell people that they could set their computers up to run over night playing a DVD with full brightness. This usually kills the battery quickly and then the battery and system will sit the rest of the night inactive (this is also a nice way to make sure the system isn't doing anything to data-critical during calibration).

1. Plug the battery into unit and external power to the computer and charge battery to 100%.
2. That is it. Li-Ion batteries need to be calibrated only once. If used appropriately the battery life space (and charge capacity) will hold longer than manufacturer definitions.

Comment: please can you provide a source to say that a non-removalble battery does not need calibrating?

Comment: As per [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1490): Portables with built-in batteries
Current Apple portable computer batteries are pre-calibrated and do not require the calibration procedure outlined in this article.

Comment: excellent, I have added to your question. Its good information but not applicable to the OP as they have installed a new battery which suggests that it is not the original pre-calibrated version