# Is it advisable to calibrate the battery on a iPhone?

Tags: iphone, battery

I want to ask the same question as here: [Is it advisable to calibrate the battery on a MacBook?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73310/is-it-advisable-to-calibrate-the-battery-on-a-macbook)
but for iPhone.

Should I calibrate iPhone's battery? For example with make it completely empty and full charge it after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Apple Support Communities user tip](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-9732):

> So what are the "rules" for charging? The most basic one is charge
>   whenever you want to, for a long as you want to. There's no reason to
>   let the device drain completely before charging (in fact, it's a bad
>   idea to do that on a regular basis), and there's no need to wait until
>   it reaches 100% before removing it from the power source.  You can
>   charge when it's at 40% and disconnect when it reaches 80%, or any
>   other values, without hurting the phone. And you don't have to turn it
>   off to charge it; in fact, you shouldn't.

There is no reason to calibrate the battery.